# When methods are throwing exceptions in jUnit

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, junit

What do you do with methods that throw exceptions in jUnit tests? As you see the `addAnswer` method in the `Question` class may throw a exception. In the `shouldFailifTwoAnswerAreCorrect` method I want to check if the exception is thrown but in the `shouldAddAnswersToQuestion`

Should I add throws `MultipleAnswersAreCorrectException` from the private `addAnswerToQuestion` method and try/catch in the `shouldAddAnswersToQuestion` or throw it in that method too?

What do you do when methods throw exception(s) in tests?

```
public class QuestionTest {

    private Question question;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        question = new Question("How many wheels are there on a car?", "car.png");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAddAnswersToQuestion() {

        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 3", false));
        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 4", true));
        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 5", false));
        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 6", false));

        assertEquals(4, question.getAnswers().size());
    }

    @Test(expected = MultipleAnswersAreCorrectException.class)
    public void shouldFailIfTwoAnswersAreCorrect() {

        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 3", false));
        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 4", true));
        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 5", true));
        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 6", false));
    }

    private void addAnswerToQuestion(Answer answer) {
        question.addAnswer(answer);
    }
}
```

Method in Question class

```
public void addAnswer(Answer answer) throws MultipleAnswersAreCorrectException {

    boolean correctAnswerAdded = false;

    for (Answer element : answers) {
        if (element.getCorrect()) {
            correctAnswerAdded = true;
        }
    }

    if (correctAnswerAdded) {
        throw new MultipleAnswersAreCorrectException();
    } else {
        answers.add(answer);    
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add `throws` declaration to `addAnswerToQuestion` and then either try/catch the exception or use `expected` attribute or `@Test`:

```
@Test(expected=IOException.class)
public void test() {
    // test that should throw IOException to succeed.
}
```

Comment: So you don't do anything other than normal in the try/catch in a jUnit test? What do you do if for a strange reason throws an exception (even though it shouldn't in this method)? Do you write .printStackTrace() etc?

Comment: Exactly. So just don't catch then you get the stack trace to start debugging.

Comment: @his A little trouble understanding what you meant. Do you mean I should not do anything in catch or that I should print the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

In `shouldAddAnswersToQuestion` test if you are not expecting `MultipleAnswersAreCorrectException` then you can surround the block in a try/catch and write an assert fail condition e.g.

```
    @Test
public void shouldAddAnswersToQuestion() {
  try{
       addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 3", false));
       addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 4", true));
       addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 5", false));
       addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 6", false));
       assertEquals(4, question.getAnswers().size());
   }catch(MultipleAnswersAreCorrectException  e){
     Assert.assertFail("Some self explainable failure statement");
   }
}
```

I think its always better to make the test fail, Instead of throwing the exception from the test, because all the test should fail for an assertin failure and not because of exception.

Comment: Absolutely not! This way all the information why the test failed is completely lost. Otherwise you just could look into the stack trace. Test frameworks know how to handle methods that throw exceptions.

Comment: @his This exception is a user defined exception so there is nothing to debug, we should know when this exception will be raised, so there is no point to printing the stacktrace. Test should have only 2 outputs either pass or fail.

Comment: You should *not* print the stacktrace. An unexpected exception *is* a fail.

Comment: Two things we know that this exception can happen, second thing exception is different from test assertion failure

Comment: Should this exception happen in this test? Add it as expected exception. Should it not happen? Test fails. It may happen? You are not writing a unit test.