# test exception is not thrown

Tags: java, testing, exception, junit4

I'm creating an integration test:

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@AdditionalClasses({FollowUpActivityRepository.class, SettingsPropertiesProducer.class})
public class FollowUpActivityFeaturesTest {

  @Inject protected FollowUpActivityService fuaService;

  @Test
  public void DigitalInputTOFollowUpActivityFIELDS()
  { 
    FollowUpActivityDTO dto = new FollowUpActivityDTO();
    dto.setId("id");
    dto.setTimestamp(Date.from(Instant.now()));
    dto.setDueTimestamp(Date.from(Instant.now()));
    dto.setClosingTimestamp(Date.from(Instant.now()));
    dto.setMatter("matter");
    dto.setComment("comment");

    this.fuaService.createOrUpdate(dto); 

  }

}
```

`createOrUpdate` is like:

```
public void createOrUpdate(FollowUpActivityDTO dto) throws RepositorySystemException
```

So, I need to check this exception is **NOT** thrown.

I'd like to do it elegantly.

Actually, I'm using junit 4.12 and hamcrest 2.0.0.0.

Any ideas?

**Example**

In .NET, I'm using NSubstitute in order to get that:

```
this.apiClient.Invoking(c => c.GrantAuthorization()).ShouldNotThrow();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** after you reversed the meaning of the question:

If you want your test to fail if an Exception is thrown, you have nothing more to do than just declare an Exception in the `throws` part of the test method signature (this is not mandatory if the Exception thrown is some kind of `RuntimeException`, but yours obviously isn't):

```
public void DigitalInputTOFollowUpActivityFIELDS() throws Exception
```

No need to specify any kind of Exception. Anyway, any jUnit test will fail as soon as an unhandled Exception is thrown (which is the behavior you're expecting).

From [this blog](http://www.kyleblaney.com/junit-best-practices/):

> Test methods that declare that they throw one particular type of
>   exception are brittle because they must be changed whenever the method
>   under test changes.

---

**Old answer:**

Just write your test annotation like this:

```
@Test(expected=RepositorySystemException.class)
```

This way, the test method will succeed as soon as this exception is thrown.

See [javadoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html#expected()).

**Edit** after your comment:

To validate the test against any Exception, just:

```
@Test(expected=Exception.class)
```

But as B. Dalton suggested, that seems kind of dangerous, as this test would then pass on *any* Exception, no matter if it's the one you're expecting or any other.

For the sake of completeness, you can also do something like this (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16725280/1679537)):

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void DigitalInputTOFollowUpActivityFIELDS()
{ 
    FollowUpActivityDTO dto = new FollowUpActivityDTO();
    dto.setId("id");
    dto.setTimestamp(Date.from(Instant.now()));
    dto.setDueTimestamp(Date.from(Instant.now()));
    dto.setClosingTimestamp(Date.from(Instant.now()));
    dto.setMatter("matter");
    dto.setComment("comment");

    thrown.expect(Exception.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("something you can check"); // if needed

    this.fuaService.createOrUpdate(dto); 
}
```

This way, `createOrUpdate` will still be able to validate the test by throwing any kind of Exception, but at least the rest of the method won't.

See javadoc for [ExpectedException](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html).

Or, of course, the good old solution:

```
try {
    this.fuaService.createOrUpdate(dto); 
    fail("this should throw an exception");
} catch (RepositorySystemException e){
    // pass
} catch (Exception e){
    // pass
}
```

This is less elegant, but allows you to tweak the exception handling as you need.

Comment: I need to check any Exception is thrown.

Comment: `I need to check this exception is now thrown.` That's not what you asked, but see edited answer.

Comment: Jordi, I find it hard to imagine that this test should succeed if _any_ exception is thrown. Are you sure you want this test to pass if, say, `NullPointerException` is thrown?

Comment: @B.Dalton Excellent point, I added it in the answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Ahhh! I did a typing mistake. I've amended it. I meant `I need to check any exception is NOT thrown`. The trouble for me is `this.fuaService.createOrUpdate(dto)` can throw an `RepositoryException`, and Java compiler tells me I need to surround this sentence with a `try/catch` or add a `throws declaration` on the test method signature. Sorry! I've added an example using NSubstitute on my post.

Comment: @Jordi Well... edited. That's a bad practice on SO to change the meaning of a question when answers already exists, as this invalidates them.