# How to verify the details of exceptions thrown in JUnit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit, mockito

I'm writing a JUnit/Mockito test where an exception is expected to be thrown. Of course I can just do this:

```
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
```

But it doesn't let me to do anything else after it was thrown. So I was thinking maybe something more like:

```
Exception actualEx = null;
try {
    // Act
    sut.doStuff();
} catch (final Exception ex) {
    actualEx = ex;
}
// Assert
assertTrue(IllegalArgumentException.class.equals(actualEx.getClass()));
// ... perhaps verify the exception details
verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockObject);
```

This seems pretty ugly and feels like it could be improved - is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried the ExpectedException rule? http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=1530

Comment: or [catch-exception](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/), too bad however they use FEST-Assert (almost dead) instead of AssertJ

Comment: @Brice Thanks but would prefer to avoid add-on libraries if I can help it...

Comment: I understand (I'm still not a fan of adding Nth libraries), though catch-exception is enable us to follow Arrange/Act/Assert or BDD principles in test which is more interesting regarding the readability of the test.

Comment: An alternative duplicate with answers that also cover JUnit5's `AssertThrows`:  [How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be consistent throughout your project - although there are three or four different ways to solve this problem, you absolutely should *not* try to use all of them.

Since the `ExpectedException` mechanism is the most powerful and most versatile way, I would recommend you learn to use it.  Its advantages include the following.

- It's easy to check both the type of the thrown exception and its message.
- You can do more sophisticated matching on the exception if you need to.
- You can check exactly which line of your test throws the exception, by placing the `expect` call immediately before the line that you expect to throw the exception.

At the risk of sounding like a shampoo advertisement - now that I've used `ExpectedException`, I wouldn't use anything else!

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way. It depends :-) Take a look at the JUnit Wiki: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Exception-testing

Answer (score 1):

Just an add-on here. I agree with Stefan's post and that is a good resources. Here are the guidelines I follow.

1. I only use the `@Test(expected=...)` if there is only one method call in the test and that is the method under test. That is because of the following... what if you have `@Test(expect=NullPointerException.class)` and you have a bug somewhere in the setup of the test that throws this exception. The test will pass having never called the method under test.
2. So, in all other cases I use the `ExpectedException` Rule with the `expect` immediately before the call to the method under test. In this way if an exception is thrown in the code prior to the method call the test will fail.

I never use the catch / fail mechanism because it is too easy for someone inexperienced to remove the `fail` and this would allow the test to pass erroneously. If I need to do extra verification I still use `ExpectedException` and rethrow the exception inside the catch block after I have done any additional verification.