# JUnit -- annotations

Tags: junit, annotations

Would it be safe to say that JUnit processes all and only the annotated members in the test-class 
and sees the rest as plain Java code-- Doesn't look at the un-annotated members.

I haven't gone far deep into JUnit-- yet, but from what i see so far, this is how it is. 
Looking to pin it down if it's a general case.

//===================================

**ADD:** see the use of its **ExpectedException** for instance. 
It's "seeing" its **ExpectedException** object and setting aside the exception object it's holding 
when that **ExceptionObject** is annotated with **@Rule**. See [How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests).

If you comment out **@Rule**, the **ExceptionObject** declared and instantiated there 
is a plain class member, just as 
any other class member-- nothing to do with **JUnit** this time. 
**JUnit** not minding it-- seeing that exception and terminating when that exception occurs.

Looking to see whether this a general rule-- how JUnit operates while working on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this is true for JUnit 4 (except constructors). But don't rely on it. Mostly JUnit uses [TestClass](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/model/TestClass.html) objects, which only give access to methods and fields with annotations.