# How to work with junit ExpectedException?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, hamcrest, expected-exception

I'm trying to work with `ExpectedExceptions` for JUnit. I tried already this:

```
public class ExpectedTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();


    @Test
    public void test() {
        thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

}
```

which raises me the following Exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     at
>   org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.isThrowable(JUnitMatchers.java:103)
>     at
>   org.junit.rules.ExpectedExceptionMatcherBuilder.build(ExpectedExceptionMatcherBuilder.java:27)
>     at
>   org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.handleException(ExpectedException.java:198)
>     at
>   org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.access$500(ExpectedException.java:85)
>     at
>   org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:177)
>     at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 33 more

When I do it like this:

```
public class ExpectedTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        thrown = ExpectedException.none();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

}
```

I get a simple NullPointerException! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher` suggests that you should make sure that hamcrest-core is on the runtime classpath, or add it if it's missing

Comment: I finally found it out myself: it was a Wrong Version of org.hamcrest, because of different Maven dependencys from Mockito and JUnit.

Comment: Aye, they both depend on hamcrest. Maybe you should post this as an answer and choose it as the correct one?!

Comment: Also, makes sure you're running one of the JUnit releases that have removed the built-in Hamcrest JAR.

Answer (score 2):

You need following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the test that is supposed to throw the exception:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
```

Comment: I know about Expected Parameter... but I found the class ÈxpectedException` and want to use that! http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.8.1/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.java

Comment: @RafaelT the link I added for duplication reason have all the details you require.

Comment: @sakura I saw that. But my question was really clear. I have done exactly what was suggested (even in the class or in the Answers) but it DOESN'T work!