# Ask JUnit to throw exception in method its calling

Tags: java, exception, junit

Is there a way I can tell a JUnit to enter a method and throw an exception so that I can test error handling scenarios?

Thanks

Comment: JUnit no, one of the mocking libraries, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not in the way you describe it. A typical solution would be to mock the object in question and instruct the mock to throw an exception when the method is invoked.

Take a look at [Mockito](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html), which is a popular framework for mocking in Java. The code would be essentially:

```
doThrow(new SomeException()).when(yourMockedObject).yourMethod();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this would be helpful: [How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests)

You will have to simulate those exception scenarios as well.

Comment: -1 The question is how to trigger the exception. This answer doesn't explain how to do that.