# JUnit Eclipse check if exception is thrown?

Tags: eclipse, junit

hey guys i have this Junit test code for factorial

```
@org.junit.Test
public void testIterationAAA()
{
    Iteration test = new Iteration("AAA");
    int result = test.factorial("AAA");

    assertEquals("exceptionMessage",result);

}
```

supposedly since a string's factorial cant be calculated the exception i made should be thrown but how to test it using Junit??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests)

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.junit.Assert;

...

@org.junit.Test
public void testIterationAAA()
{
    try {
         Iteration test = new Iteration("AAA");
         int result = test.factorial("AAA");
         // The above line is expected to throw an exception.
         // If the code does not throw an exception, fail the test.
         Assert.fail("An exception should have been thrown");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         // Nothing to do.  Exception was expected in this test case.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `expected` attribute

```
@Test(expected=SomeException.class)
```