# in JUnit, when should I use assertEquals() when should I use try...catch to verify results?

Tags: junit

e.g, in `verifySthIsSetCorrectly()` of following code, should I use `assertEquals()` to check result or should I throw exception so that it is caught by `try...catch` of the caller and let caller to handle?

```java
@Parameters
public static Collection<object[]> methodParams() {
    List<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    /* arg, errorString */
    params.add(new Object[] {"arg1", null /*errorString*/});
    params.add(new Object[] {"arg2", ERROR_STRING1 /*errorString*/});
}
@Test
public void sampleTest () {
    try {
        MethodAndWait(arg);
        assertNull("expect error String" + errorString, errorString);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        assertNotNull("expect error String" + errorString, errorString);
        assertTrue(ex.getMessage().contains(errorString));
    }
}

private void MethodAndWait() {
    call_remote_server_to_have_sth_set;
    verifySthIsSetCorrectly();
}

private void verifySthIsSetCorrectly() {
    int sth = getSth();
    assertEquals(sth == "5");
}
```

Comment: The assertEquals is wrong. It must be `assertEquals(5, sth)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a JUnit test, you should use assertions like `assertEquals()` to verify the result of a method call or the state of an object:

```java
@Test
public void addingTwoNumbersShouldWork() {
  int result = calculator.add(5, 7);

  assertEquals(12, result);
  assertFalse(calculator.hasOverflow());
}
```

It's extremely rare to use `try` and `catch` in a JUnit test for anything other than testing that a code block throws an expected exception:

```java
@Test
public void setColorShouldThrowNullPointerExceptionOnNullInput() {
  try {
    deathRay.setColor(null);
    fail("expected NullPointerException");
  } catch (NullPointerException expected) {
    assertThat(expected.getMessage(), contains("death ray color"));
  }
}
```

You do not need to use `try` and `catch` if the method you are testing happens to throw an exception:

```java
@Test
public void fireDeathRay() throws DeathRayException {
  deathRay.fire();
}
```

In the above test, if `fire()` throws a `DeathRayException` (or a runtime exception) the `fireDeathRay` test will fail.

In JUnit4, it's even rarer to use `try` and `catch`, because [you can use the `ExpectedException` rule to check if a call throws an expected exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2935935/95725).

Comment: got it. so should use private void verifySthIsSetCorrectly() throw exception {} because the purpose is not to test its expected error,  but to test expected error of sampleTest()

Comment: @user389955 Sorry, I don't understand what your test is doing enough to agree or disagree with your comment

Answer (score 1):

Your test should be

```
@Test
public void sampleTest () {
    call_remote_server_to_have_sth_set;
    int sth = getSth();
    assertEquals(5, sth);
}
```

I would recommend to read an introduction to testing with JUnit if you haven't already done it.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. the code in verifySthIsSetCorrectly() is not as short as what I typed. that is why I put it in a function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take the unusual step of adding another answer after my answer was accepted. The previous answer focused on the question raised in the summary, but I wanted to focus on the code.

I think one of the reasons why you were wondering what to do is because the test `sampleTest()` is testing two completely different things. **Your test method is testing normal behavior and exceptional behavior in the same test method.**

Instead, **split out the testing of the exceptional cases into their own test methods**. For example:

```java
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class SampleTest {

  @Test
  public void methodAndWaitShouldAcceptNonNullValue() {
    ClassUnderTest.methodAndWait("arg1")
  }

  @Test
  public void methodAndWaitShouldThrowWhenGivenNullValue() {
    try {
      ClassUnderTest.methodAndWait(null);
      fail("NullPointerException was not thrown");
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
      assertTrue(ex.getMessage().contains(ERROR_STRING1));
    }
  }
}
```

This has several advantages:

1. If `methodAndWait("arg1")` throws an exception, the test will fail with a useful stack trace
2. If `methodAndWait(null)` throws something other than `NullPointerException`, the test will fail with a useful stack trace
3. If `methodAndWait(null)` doesn't throw anything, the test will fail with a useful message
4. The intent of both tests is very clear

If you need to test with multiple arguments, you can use the `Enclosed` runner:

```java
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class SampleTest {

  @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
  public static class WhenPassingNonNull {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<object[]> methodParams() {
      List<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
      /* arg, errorString */
      params.add(new Object[] {"arg1", "result1"});
      params.add(new Object[] {"arg3", "result3"});
    }

    public final String arg;
    public final String actualResult;

    public SampleTest(String arg, String actualResult) {
      this.arg = arg;
      this.actualResult = actualResult;
    }

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
      String actualResult = ClassUnderTest.methodAndWait(arg);

      assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
  }

  @RunWith(JUnit4.class)
  public static class WhenPassingNull {
    @Test
    public void shouldThrowNullPointerException() {
      try {
        ClassUnderTest.methodAndWait(null);
        fail();
      } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        assertTrue(ex.getMessage().contains(ERROR_STRING1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, NamshubWriter: the question I really wanted to ask is: I want to test sampleTest() to make sure with different arguments(I have a lot of arguments, and corresponding errorMessage to test), we get corresponding errorMessage correctly. I do not mean to test methodAndWait() although I have to call methodAndWait() in sampleTest(). And I assume when testing sampleTest(), methodAndWait() should always return normally. But it is possible that methodAndWait() itself may catch exception. (think about replace methodAndWait() with createTable(). we

Comment: want to run some test about a table and we call createTable() first to make table ready. but it is possible that createTable() throw an exception because table is not created successfully) in this case should I just make the test fails or should I pass the failure to sampleTest() and let sampleTest() to match the argument - errorMassage list and decide what to do?

Comment: I wont use Enclose.class because it require to change everything as static

Comment: @user389955 As long as you split tests where you expect the production code to throw from tests that expect the production code not to fail, I think you are fine. Don't worry about methods that should work but could fail with an exception;  just update your throws clause to list any checked exceptions thrown by `createTable()`. If you don't like `Enclosed` then perhaps consider using JUnit-params so you can have per-method parameters.