# Junit expect assertion called

Tags: java, junit, expected-exception

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2935935/2187510) specifically answer's my question

In Junit is there a way to make sure the code makes it past a certain point?

ex:

```
@Test(expect = SpecialException.class)
public void testMyCode() {
    essentialMethodThatCantBeMockedThatMayThrowSpecialException()

    // stuff

    actualMethodIAmTestingAndWillAlsoThrowSpecialException()
}
```

The main purpose is that I am doing a major refactor and if I can outfit my existing tests with something like an expect x number of assertions.  Then that would make sure that my tests throw exceptions for the correct reasons and not the wrong reasons.

A good example of something that does this is Qunit which has a expect(numberOfAssertions)  which will fail the test if that many assertions are not called.

I have been looking a long time for something like this in JUnit but I can't find it.