# How to test ParseException that is thrown by SimpelDateFormat?

Tags: java, testing, exception

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void doStuffThrowsParseException() {
    TestException foo = new TestException();

    exception.expect(ParseException.class);
    foo.doStuff("haha");
}
```

main

```
Date submissionT;
SimpleDateFormat tempDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
public void doStuff(String time) {
    try {
        submissionT=tempDate.parse(time);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {     
        System.out.println(e.toString() + ", " + time);
      }
}
```

results in `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "haha", haha`.

Although a ParseException is thrown the test fails. Why?

Comment: @Tunaki. This is not a duplicate. The code snippet resides from the link and it is not working

Comment: Have you read the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/156528/1743880)? Because your code doesn't have what this answer is saying you should have.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes sir, but that does not work either.

Comment: Well yes, you are catching the exception and doing nothing with it: `catch (Exception e)`.