# How to write Test case for static methods for exception part

Tags: java, junit

I need a test case for the exception part:

```
try { 
  return String.valueOf(value);
} catch (Exception e) {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: so write one.  What are you waiting for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests)

Comment: Pass in a mocked `value` which throws an exception when you call its `toString()` method.

Comment: @AndyTurner Why did you delete your answer? doesnt look too bad to me? Although, sometimes I too think that answering this low-quality questions isnt really what the community expects what should happen.

Comment: @GhostCat that was the point. What the hey, have the answer back. I feel there is sufficient "don't do that" value (see below the `---`).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class whose `toString()` method throws an exception:

```
class Throwing {
  @Override public String toString() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
}
```

and then pass an instance of this to your method in the unit test:

```
assertNull(yourMethod(new Throwing()));
```

Of course, you can use your favorite mocking framework rather than creating an explicit class like this.

---

But think very carefully about whether this method is worthwhile. It is a pretty big source of problems if you have classes whose `toString()` methods throw exceptions, and that's the only case that your method handles over and above `String.valueOf`.

In any other place in the code where you happen to perform a string conversion (e.g. `"" + instance`), instances of that class will throw an exception, and you won't be catching them there.

Consider this insidious case:

```
try {
  doSomething(instance);
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred: " + instance, e);
}
```

In this case, the exception from `instance.toString()` would only be thrown if an exception `e` is caught, but it's the exception from `toString()` which would be thrown - you'd not actually see `e` at all. Thus, it would make it much harder to see the *real* problem.

I would recommend *not* having this method at all, so not catching the exception, and using `String.valueOf(Object)` directly (or implicitly), so that you actually know when a problem occurs.

Unchecked exceptions - the only type which can be thrown by `toString()` - indicate programming errors. Don't swallow those errors, then you'll know to fix them.

Comment: hi all i got my answer by try for a long time, below is test case which is going to test string for null:                                                                                                                   
  public void toStringForNULLTest() throws Exception
  {
   new NonStrictExpectations() 
   {
   {
    new MockUp<String>() 
      {
     @Mock
     public String valueOf(Object obj) throws Exception 
     {
      throw new Exception();
     }
      };
   }
   };
   Integer a= new Integer(123);
   utilities.toString(a); 
  }

Comment: You should really update your question and not put that in a comment.