# Can we mock finally block in unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermockito

In my code I have a try-finally method.I don't want finally block for my unit testing.Can I mock the entire finally block in my class,because in my case it is just logging ?I am using PowerMockito for my unit testing.

```
try {
    String foo = obj.myMethod();
} finally {
    logger.info(obj.webService());
}
```

Comment: Why is logging an issue when you're testing ?

Comment: Why do you want to mock a block. You can only mock objects not blocks or loops.

Comment: Why not just mock the logger?

Comment: @alfasin because i am getting null pointer exception,while calling my webservices and i dont want any value from my webservices during my return.

Comment: You should inject a mock `obj` and potentially create an expectation for `obj.webService()`. In production, the code will call `obj.webService()`, and so in your testing you should too.

Comment: I mocked the value for foo.

Comment: Assuming that `obj` is injected (because I know you follow good practice) you can use Mockito's: `when(obj.webService()).thenReturns("")` with a mocked `obj` and you're golden.

Comment: Put whatever in your finally block in a method and mock that. But, yeah, as others have alluded, this practice is rather pointless.

Comment: @alfasin logger present in finally is giving me warning and nullpointer exception.Can I suppress it?

Comment: I don't like the approach of suppressing exceptions, but you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/156528/1057429 That said, it will be a better practice to follow Slim's advice in his answer below!

Answer (score 2):

The class you have written will invoke `logger.info(obj.webService())` and therefore your tests should exercise that.

It is not a good idea to make your class-under-test do something different depending on whether it's being run in a test or not. All you can change is its *collaborators*, often by replacing them with mocks.

In this case `obj` is the collaborator. So inject a mock of `obj`. Depending on the intent of your test, it may be enough to use the default, so the logger will log `null`, or you might need to specify a `when` to make `obj.webService()` return a valid object, or you might even want to verify that it was called.

Comment: I'm making an assumption, but the assumption is that the NPE is that the logger iteslf is null.  Properly mocking the main collaborator foo is great, but does not address the 2nd collaborator, logger.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you state that you want to avoid calling your webservices during test.

> i dont want any value from my webservices during my return.

I would argue **you also don't want this if the log level setting of your application is set to WARNING or higher**. (I'm assuming java default logging here)

The solution is then simple : use the logging form which takes a `Supplier` : [`Logger.info(Supplier<String> msgSupplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#info-java.util.function.Supplier-)

So your finally block would become :

```
} finally {
    logger.info(() -> obj.webService());
}
```

Then, for your tests, or in production for that matter, it's simply a case of setting your logging to Level.NONE, and the supplier will never be executed.