# HOW to create a JUnit test involving throwing exceptions?

Tags: java, junit

How to test an exception in the `run` function?

```
 `    public void run() {
     ArrayBlockingQueue<String> bookQueue = 
     library.getBookQueue(book);
     try {
        bookQueue.take();
        try {
            updateState(State.IN_PROGRESS);
            Thread.sleep(READ_TIME_MS);
            bookQueue.put(book);
            updateState(State.ENDED);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            bookQueue.put(book);
        }
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    finally {
        updateState(State.ENDED);
    }
   }`
```

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are asking for. What kind of exceptions? What kind of previous research did you do, regarding mocking frameworks? What tests did you yourself come up with?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests

Answer (score 1):

In the `@Test` annotation you can specify the expected exception

**For Example**

```
@Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class) 
 public void outOfBounds() {
   new ArrayList<Object>().get(1);
}
```

In the same way you can write test method and call `run` method inside of it

```
@Test(expected=Exception.class) 
 public void testRun() {
   run();
}
```

We can also make this better by considering the @GhostCat`suggestions in the comments, you can add`try-catch` in test method

```
@Test
 public void testRun() {
    tyr {
       run();
      Asserts.fail(); // 
      }
     catch(Exception ex) {
      assertTrue(//some condition);
      assertEquals(//some condition);
     }
 }
```

If `run()` method doesn't throw any exception test will fail because of `Asserts.fail()`, or in any exception case `catch` block assert statements will get executed

Comment: updated thank you sir for suggestion and guiding me, i need to learn a lot @GhostCat

Comment: To make perfectly perfect, you could assert something on that ex the catch block caught. That is the major point here : that you can check more about that exception from the production code than it's class.