# Exception won't work for me because it say it's empty somehow

Tags: java

I made a test to see if an exception works, but it doesn't work.

I get the result `java.lang.AssertionError:`

I expected the test to throw (an instance of `exceptions.employee.IllegalBonusException` and exception with message a string containing "The Bonus need to be <= 10.0")

Is that normal behavior?

I looked at similar code as an example, so this should have worked.

### The main class

```
Bonus(float bonus){
    validateBonusPercentage(bonus);
    this.bonusPercentage = bonus;


}
public void validateBonusPercentage(float bonus) {
    if (bonus > MAX_BONUS_PERCENTAGE)  throw new IllegalBonusException(IllegalBonusException.TOO_BIG_BONUS);
}
```

### The test

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException ex = ExpectedException.none();
@Test
public void WHEN_BonusIsEnter_and_BonusIsSuperiorToMax_THEN_RaiseIllegalBonuslExceptionMessage() {
    //Arrange
    ex.expect(IllegalBonusException.class);
    ex.expectMessage(IllegalBonusException.TOO_BIG_BONUS);
    //Act 
    float tooBig = 11.00f;
    //Assert
    Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalBonusException.class, () -> {
        this.bonus = new Bonus (tooBig);
        }); 
}
```

### The exception

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class IllegalBonusException extends IllegalArgumentException {

public static final String TOO_BIG_BONUS = "The Bonus need to be <= " + Bonus.MAX_BONUS_PERCENTAGE;

public IllegalBonusException(String s) {
    super(s);
}
}
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected test to throw (an instance of exceptions.employee.IllegalBonusException and exception with message a string containing "The Bonus need to be <= 10.0")

Comment: Please don't use the `javascript` tag on Java questions. They are not remotely the same.

Comment: Okay. I'm kind of new here so I didn't know it can be troublesome.

Comment: I thought they were the same thing

Comment: Updated text to clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a need for using both `ExcepectedException` and `Assertions.assertThrows`. Try using one or the other. For example, (assuming JUnit 5):

```
@Test
public void WHEN_BonusIsEnter_and_BonusIsSuperiorToMax_THEN_RaiseIllegalBonuslExceptionMessage() {

    float tooBig = 11.00f;
    Throwable exception = Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalBonusException.class, () -> {
        this.bonus = new Bonus(tooBig);
    });
    assertEquals(IllegalBonusException.TOO_BIG_BONUS, exception.getMessage());
}
```

See this SO question for more information: [How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests)