# Catching versus throwing exception for unit test

Tags: java, junit

In below code a checked exception is being thrown by ClassToTest.throwsException(). My preference is to add throws exception to the JUnit method signature instead of wrapping the code that throws an exception in a try catch. This preference is just based on the fact that I think its neater. Is there a coding convention I'm breaking here? Is there a difference in functionality from a testing point of view in throwing the exception versus try/catch in the testing method?

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestingClass {


    @Test
    public void getDataTest() throws Exception {

        new ClassToTest().throwsException();

    }

}
```

versus :

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestingClass {


    @Test
    public void getDataTest() {

        try {
            new ClassToTest().throwsException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

ClassToTest.java :

```
public class ClassToTest {

    public void throwsException() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Comment: If you catch it, the test case won't fail when it's thrown. Only catch it if you intend to test that the exception was thrown (but make sure the test would fail if it isn't thrown, e.g. with `fail()` after the statement that should throw).

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? Do you expect an `Exception` to be thrown or not?

Comment: @Turing85 no, i don't expect an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Then I do not see any benefit in adding the `try`-`catch`-block. It only increases the complexity of the code. If an exception is thrown, the test will fail. Even worse one would have to add a `fail()` to the `catch`-block to explicitly make the test fail (additional source of error if one forgets to add the `fail()`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests)

Comment: @Progman no, not a duplicate. OP wants to let the test fail if any `Exception` is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one does not expect an `Exception` to be thrown, there is no added benefit in adding a `try-catch` block to the code. Even worse, only adding a `try-catch` block will lead to the  test passing. To make the test fail, one would have to add a call to [`fail()`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/Assert.html#fail()) to make the test actually fail. This is a possible source for error (if one forgets to call `fail()`).

---

For completeness sake, I will talk shortly about how to verify that a certain `Exception` has been thrown. There are three approaches that come to my mind.

In the first attempt, one could use `try-catch`, but with an added `fail()` in the `try`-block, just after the calls that should throw the expected `Exception`. In the `catch`-block, one would then catch the expected `Exception`. All other `Exception`s would be re-thrown and thus the test would fail. This has the same downsides as its sibling mentioned above.

Second, there is the JUnit4 way by annotating the test itself with [`@Test(expected = ExpectedException.class)`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Test.html). This seems neat at first, but breaks the [Given-When-Then structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Given-When-Then) of tests, often leading to tests looking like this:

```
@Test(expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
public void test() {
    // GIVEN
    final int[] array = new int[10];

    // WHEN
    final int value = array[10];

   // THEN: an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException should be thrown
}
```

which is okay-ish.

Lastly, there is the JUnit5 way by wrapping the actual call into a call of [`assertThrows(...)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows-java.lang.Class-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable-):

```
@Test(expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
void test() {
    // GIVEN
    final int[] array = new int[10];

    // WHEN
    final Exception e = assertThrows(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class,
            () -> {
                int value = array[10];
            }
    );

   // THEN
   assertTrue(e.getMessage().contains("10"));
}
```

While this still does not properly separates the `WHEN` from the `THEN` (I think this is not possible in Java), it gives the added benefit to allow checking specific parts of the `Exception`, e.g. the message<sup>1</sup>.

I would suggest [this article over at Baelung](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assert-exception) as a further read.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>This is also possible in JUnit4, but is either done through an explicit `try-catch` block or through a very cumbersome mechanism that definitively breaks the Given-When-Then structure. For more information, please check the article over at Baelung mentioned above.</sub>

Comment: JUnit 4 also provides a `org.junit.rules.ExpectedException` test-rule where you can declaratively specify which exception (and message or other attributes) you expect, and [since JUnit 4.13](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.13.md), it also has `assertThrows`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the `throws` clause to the method declaration and let the exception bubble up, as written in the [JUnit4 FAQ - How do I write a test that fails when an unexpected exception is thrown?](https://junit.org/junit4/faq.html#atests_8):

> Declare the exception in the `throws` clause of the test method and don't catch the exception within the test method. Uncaught exceptions will cause the test to fail with an error.
>
> The following is an example test that fails when the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is raised:
>
> ```
> @Test
> public void testIndexOutOfBoundsExceptionNotRaised()
>     throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
>
>     ArrayList emptyList = new ArrayList();
>     Object o = emptyList.get(0);
> }
> ```

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` might not be a good example here, since it is a `RuntimeException`, but the approach is the same for other exceptions.