# Alternatives to the deprecated ExpectedException.none() in JUnit 4.13

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4, junit-rule

I am trying to use the  `@Rule` annotation with `ExpectedException`

The **ExceptedException.none()** method to initialize a variable type of ExceptedException says it has been deprecated what are the alternatives to initialize an object of the ExceptedException.
Example:

```
public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testThrownException() throws Exception {
    expectedException.expect(CustomException.class);
    expectedException.expectMessage("Exception Message");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you read [the deprecation notice](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html#none())?

> **Deprecated.** Since 4.13 [`Assert.assertThrows`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,%20org.junit.function.ThrowingRunnable)) can be used to verify that your code throws a specific exception.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46514550/733345) for an example:

Comment: Works great, thanks! 

I was so engrossed in looking for a workaround for this that I did not read the workings of **Assert.assertThrows**, the best being the flexibility to choose assertion framework and make assertions on the caught exception.

Comment: The problem in my opinion is that the deprecation is done on the method `none()` but surely should be done on the class `ExpectedException`? I was looking for an alternative method of using `ExpectedException` but that's not the migration strategy.