# How to write junit test case for if block throwing exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
if(str == null){
  throw new Exception("exception occurred");
}
```

I'm excepting to write a unit test case for the above code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests)

Comment: while running the test case if block coverage is not at all happening